# What is a inhibitory tone when talking about neurons?

Tags: neuroscience, cell-biology, neurology

In this SE answer: [Could an "overactive" brain increase the chances of Alzheimer's Disease?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/788/could-an-overactive-brain-increase-the-chances-of-alzheimers-disease#comment900_788)

user @nico used the word `inhibitory tone` What does that mean?

More examples of it used:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18234887

http://www.cell.com/neuron/abstract/S0896-6273(11)00479-X

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neurons communicate electrochemically. That is, when a signal arrives to a neuron it *fires* a series of electrical signals, called **action potentials**.
Action potentials are depolarization events that propagate along the neuronal membrane, down to the neuronal terminal. 
The terminal of a neuron is (with some exceptions) in contact with another neuron, via a structure called **synapse**.
When the depolarization arrives at the terminal, it allows the entry of calcium, which then mediates the release of a chemical substance, a **neurotransmitter** into the synaptic space. Finally, neurotransmitters act on the postsynaptic neuron, by binding to specific receptors on its cell membrane and can either stimulate it, in which case the postsynaptic neuron will fire more and release more of its neurotransmitter or inhibit it, in which case the opposite happens.

The textbook example of a stimulatory neurotransmitter is glutamate, and the inhibitory one is GABA<sup>1</sup>.

In various areas of the brain certain neurons are constantly receiving inputs from GABAergic afferents. This means that those neurons are constantly receiving a GABA stimulus that inhibits them, and are thus under a constant **inhibitory tone**. This will prevent their firing until a sufficiently potent stimulatory stimulus arrives or until the inhibitory tone is somehow released (for instance if the inhibitory GABAergic afferents are themselves inhibited by some of their own afferents).

---

<sup>1</sup>note that this is not always true: GABA can also be stimulatory in various situations